# HTACCESS Rewrite to HTTPS considering existing rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am forcinge requests for named index files to drop the index file filename, and force non-www here:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html?|php)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php)$  http://techsupportheroes.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

But I need to redirect all requests to http://techsupportheroes.com/cart/index.php to https://techsupportheroes.com/cart/index.php

This is not my area of expertise. Looking for an elegant solution if someone has a moment.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://$1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# remove index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(html?|php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php)$  http://techsupportheroes.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

#force https for /cart/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(cart)/index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I need to redirect all requests to
>   http://techsupportheroes.com/cart/index.php to
>   https://techsupportheroes.com/cart/index.php"

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule /cart/index.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```